# Issue installing Electrum on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, python3, bitcoin

I followed all the steps the docs suggest:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
wget https://download.electrum.org/3.3.6/Electrum-3.3.6.tar.gz
wget https://download.electrum.org/3.3.6/Electrum-3.3.6.tar.gz.asc
gpg --verify Electrum-3.3.6.tar.gz.asc
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pip
python3 -m pip install --user Electrum-3.3.6.tar.gz[fast]
```

No errors.

Then I try to run: `electrum create`:
`electrum: command not found`

Then: `find . -name electrum`:
`./.local/bin/electrum`
`./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/electrum`

Then: `~/.local/bin$ chmod +x electrum`
Then again: `electrum create`
still `command not found`

I can start electrum with: `~/.local/bin$ ./electrum create`
But not the way the docs suggest I should be able to, with just: `electrum create`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

This is on a fresh 18.04 server.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect there are things to polish with the new `.local` directory structure in Ubuntu and how applications use it...

I would recommend you to repeat the command without the `--user` parameter from the user console (If `--user` is used the dependencies are not later correctly found):

`python3 -m pip install Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz`

It will be quick as all packages are already downloaded.

Create a symbolic link:

`sudo ln -s ~/.local/bin/electrum /usr/local/bin/electrum`

Then you can run electrum with:

`electrum`

Answer (score 1):

Try typing just:

```
electrum
```

in your terminal.

I think its generally easier to use the AppImage as that has all dependencies included and is only one thing to do, and works across all LInux Os's. All you have to do is chmod +x on the AppImage and then double click it and it will work. If you prefer to install it into the Ubuntu system (have it show up in your menus), this is also easily done with the AppImage Launcher.

Docs on system [integration](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki)

AppImage [website](https://appimage.org/)